# Let $M$ is compact Riemann surface, if $\omega$ is a 2-form and $\int_{M} \omega =0$ then there exists a smooth function $f$ such that $\omega=d*df$

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, riemann-surfaces, hodge-theory

I want to show that:

> $(*)$If $\omega \in \Omega^{2}(M)$, which $M$ is compact Riemann surface and $\Omega^{2}(M)$ means 2-form, and $\int_{M} \omega =0$, then there exists a smooth function $f$(i.e. $f\in \Omega^{0}(M)$) such that $\omega=d*df$ .

---

I try to imitate the method of proof of the $\textbf{Hodge Decomposition}$:

> Let $\omega \in A^1(\Sigma)$, then $$\omega=\omega_{h}+df+*dg,$$
>   where $\omega_{h}\in H^1$ and $f,g\in A^0(\Sigma).$

The proof of the Hodge Decomposition as following Three Steps:

Step 1. To establish a complete Hilbert space

Step 2. To seek $df, *dg$ (Similar to the existing of the solution of PDE)

Step 3. regularity. (To use the Weyl Lemma.)

Define $X=\{\phi \in \Omega^{0}(M): \int_{M} \phi d\sigma=0\}$ with $\int_{M}d\sigma=1$ and $\forall \psi, \phi \in X$, define the inner product, $$(\psi,\phi)=\langle d\psi, d\phi\rangle=\int_{\Sigma} d\psi \wedge *d\phi.$$

We could show that $\bar{X}$ is a complete Hilbert space. Moreover, if $f\in \bar{X}$, then $f\in X$(i.e. $\bar{X}\subset L^2(X,d\sigma)$).

Then $\forall \phi \in C^{\infty}(X)$, we seek $g$ s.t. 
$$ \int_{\Sigma}d\phi \wedge \omega =\int_{\Sigma}d\phi \wedge *dg.$$
Here we could define a bounded linear functional $l$, which 
$$l: X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
$$\phi \longmapsto  \int_{\Sigma}d\phi \wedge \omega$$

Using the Resiz representation theorem, $\exists g\in \bar{X}$, s.t.
$$l(\phi)=\langle \phi, \bar{g}\rangle, \forall g\in \bar{X}.$$
where using the regularity implies $g\in X$.

In the next, 
$$\int_{M}\phi \omega= \int_{M} f d*d\phi=\int_{M} d\phi \wedge *df \ (*),$$
we get 
$$ \int_{M} \phi (\omega-d*df)=0, \forall \phi \in C^{\infty}(X),$$
Hence, $\omega-*dg$ is closed form. Finished the proof of Hodge theorem.

---

How to construct similarly of such linear functional to prove the problem $(*)?

Comment: This is false. If $\omega = d*df$, then $\int_M\omega = 0$ by Stokes' Theorem, but this is not always true (take $\omega$ to be a volume form).

Comment: @Michael Albanese Sorry, there is a condition I ignore: $\int_{M} \omega =0$.

Comment: The idea is similar to the proof of Hodge decomposition.

Comment: $d\ast df$ is 1-form. How $\omega=d\ast d f$ ?

Comment: @HKLee Why $d*df$ is 1-form? I think there is no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\int \omega = 0$, $\omega = d\alpha$ for some one form $\alpha$. Using the Hodge decomposition, 
$$\alpha = d^* \omega_1 + dg + \alpha_3, $$
where $\Delta \alpha_3 = 0$. Thus 
$$\omega = d \alpha = dd^*\omega_1 = \pm d(*d*\omega_1) = d *df,$$
where $f = \pm *\omega_1$.

Comment: Why dose $\alpha$ exist?  Does $ \omega_{1} \in \Omega^{0}?$ Why does exist the $\pm$?

Comment: If $M$ is orientable, then consider $N$ containing $M$ s.t. $N-M$ is homeomorphic to $(\partial M)\times [0,1]$. Then there is extension $\omega'$ on $N$ s.t. $\int_{N'} \ \omega '=0$ and $\omega'=0$ near $\partial N$. If $\partial N'$ shrinks to a point, then we have a close manifold. So $\omega'$ is an exact form.

Comment: @HKLee Could you follow the idea as my new edited? Thanks!

Comment: @HKLee Maybe we do not sure if $M$ is orientable.